# SQLCMD mode: Environment variable syntax

Tags: t-sql, environment-variables, ssms, sqlcmd

I assume the best way to set my SSMS output file path during runtime of T-SQL, is to use SQLCMD mode.
How do I use environment variables (e.g. %systemroot%) in the code? The following bombs:

```
:set mypath %systemroot%
:out $(mypath)"\the_result.txt"
select * from myTab
```

And also perhaps: Is there an environment variable for the folder of the Query.sql with this code, or for the working folder?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How to Read Environment Variables in SQL Server Using T-SQL**

To read Environment variables in T-SQL, you can use the `xp_cmdshell` extended stored procedure in SQL Server.

The following example shows how to read the %windir% environment variable, which gives the Windows directory path on SQL Server using xp_cmdshell:

```
DECLARE @windir nvarchar(255)
CREATE TABLE #Tmp
(
EnvVar nvarchar(255)
)
INSERT INTO #Tmp exec xp_cmdshell 'echo %windir%'
SET @windir = (SELECT TOP 1 EnvVar from #Tmp)

SELECT @windir as 'Windows Directory'
```

**NOTE:** To run this command, you need to be a member of the sysadmin fixed server. If you want others to be able to execute this command, you will have to explicitly grant them permission to execute the xp_cmdshell stored procedure.

Find more information about this stored procedure at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-AR/library/ms175046.aspx). 
[Source](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/46626)

**Using command prompt environment variables within sqlcmd**
In the following example, four environment variables are set and then called from sqlcmd.

```
C:\>SET tablename=Person.Person
C:\>SET col1=FirstName
C:\>SET col2=LastName
C:\>SET title=Ms.
C:\>sqlcmd -d AdventureWorks2012
1> SELECT TOP 5 $(col1) + ' ' + $(col2) AS Name
2> FROM $(tablename)
3> WHERE Title ='$(title)'
4> GO
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Some caveats:

[1] Supported SQLCMD scripts in SSMS

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/edit-sqlcmd-scripts-with-query-editor?view=sql-server-ver15

[2] From the above link, which you appear to have read (a long time ago), read further about the :!!

Then have a look at this as an example

```
:!!set
```

...which is the same as this...

```
!!set
```

anyway the output shows it's SystemRoot, not systemroot.

[3] SSMS includes the completion time by default

**i) Tools > Options > Query Execution > SQL Server > Advanced.**

**ii) Uncheck the Show Completion Time checkbox.**
And so, to the answer...

```
:out $(SystemRoot)"\the_result.txt"
select * from myTab 
:out stdout
```

I got this...

```html
<p style="color: red"> 
Unable to redirect output to C:\WINDOWS\the_result.txt. <br>
Access to the path 'C:\WINDOWS\the_result.txt' is denied.<br>
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 31<br>
Invalid object name 'myTab'.
</p>
```

...then again, why would I want to output a query to a file in C:\WINDOWS for a table that doesn't exist! ;)
Let's create a test table and the final script is:

```
--[4] Turn off (x row affected)
set nocount on
GO

create table myTab(
    ID int identity(1,1) not null
    ,colTest varchar(20) null
);
insert into myTab
    select 'Hello world';
go

--change the output to be a file in the temporary directory
--This file will be overwritten each time the script is ran
:out $(TEMP)\the_result.txt
--print this to the output
print ' <- [5] There might be squiggly bits'
print '$(SystemRoot)'
select * from myTab
go

--reset the output
:out stdout
--use type to see file contents
!!type %TEMP%\the_result.txt
--let's be tidy
!!del %TEMP%\the_result.txt
drop table myTab
go
```

Messages output

```
ï»¿ <- [5] There might be squiggly bits
C:\WINDOWS
ID          colTest
----------- --------------------
1           Hello world
```

### Summary

With doing nothing else, you have access to environment variables once in SQLCMD mode in SSMS

```
print '$(SystemRoot)'
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your contribution! I will read this at my leisure, it seems useful ... All the best